# Using a function to repeat function over a collection of filenames

Tags: r, function, lapply, sapply, mapply

I would like to write a [function](/questions/tagged/function) to repeat a chunk of code over a collection of file names (names of files present in my working directory) in [r](/questions/tagged/r). I would also like to **save the outputs of each line as a global environment object** if possible. General structure of what I am trying to do is given below. Function name is made up.

```
global_environment_object_1 <- anyfunction("filename and extension").
# Repeat this over a set of filenames in the working directory and save each as a separate 
# global environment object with separate names.
```

A Real life example can be:

```
sds22 <- get_subdatasets("EVI_2017_June_2.hdf")
sds23 <- get_subdatasets("EVI_2016_June_1.hdf")
```

-where object names and file names are changing and the total number of files is 48.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `anyfunction` or `get_subdatasets` is already written? What do you want to store in `sds22` ?  Is there a specific way that you want to name this objects?

Comment: - No those functions are ready-to-use functions present in packages

- The objects can be named in anyway, but sequential naming would be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
#Get all the filenames
all_files <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)
#Probably to be specific
#all_files <- list.files(patter = "\\.hdf$", full.names = TRUE)
#apply get_subdatasets to each one of them
all_data <- lapply(all_files, get_subdatasets)
#Assign name to list output
names(all_data) <- paste0('sds', seq_along(all_data))
#Get the data in global environment
list2env(all_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: One more thing.
gdal_translate(src_dataset = sds1[2], dst_dataset = "EVI_2019_August_1.tif")
How do I apply the above code to all the items in the list you suggested while changing the file name in dsc_dataset argument, so that they each have a different name. Thanks in advance mate.

Comment: @KO88 I am not sure which package `gdal_translate` is from. Probably, you might want to add that as a new question.